# Tell Git to upload the contents of a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Does anyone know how its possible to pull add the contents of a submodule in GIT into the main repository, but still allow the submodule to be updatable if you perform a git pull request within the submodule?

This way, when you upload changes of your repository then your contents will be uploaded alongside all of the contents of the submodule. But if the submodule contains updates then it can be updated directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tool that does exactly this without the need to use submodules. It contains a manifest file where you can identify the .git repositories available via http and then have the tool download them and add them to your repo. None of the downloaded repos will be picked up as submodules within the parent git application.

https://github.com/yearofmoo/Git-Depend

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this. The point is to store the version of the submodule your parent repo requires. When you make changes to a submodule, say, `vendor/plugins/my-plugin`, you should be committing the changes to the submodule, then `git add vendor/plugins/my-plugin` to update the submodule version in the parent repo's `.gitmodules`. This is how you store changes to a submodule within the containing parent repository.

Answer (score 0):

The module is under management by GIT. So you should be able to pull/push them anytime. You don't have to put them into main repo.